# Fixed Point Derivative Question

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f,g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$, $x_0$ a fixed point in $(0,1)$. Assume $f(x_0) = g(x_0) = 0$, $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x_0$ and $g'(x_0) \neq 0$.

Prove: $$ \lim_{t \to x_0} \frac{f(t)}{g(t)} = \frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}$$

Hints preferred rather than being given the whole solution. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what is a fixed point ?

Comment: This is L'Hopital's rule, no?

Comment: 1. If $x_0$ is a fixed point, then $x_0 = f(x_0) = 0$ but you said that $x_0 \in (0, 1)$. 2. Do you mean $t \to x_0$ in your limit?

Comment: I think “fixed” just means “given” here.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified... we may not apply L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a derivative is itself a limit

$$
\frac{f'(x_0)}{g'(x_0)} =  \frac{ \lim_{t \to x_0}\frac{{f(t) - f(x_0)}}{t-x_0}}{ \lim_{t \to x_0}\frac{g(t)-g(x_0)}{t-x_0}} =\lim_{t \to x_0}
\frac{ \frac{{f(t) - f(x_0)}}{t-x_0}}{\frac{g(t)-g(x_0)}{t-x_0}} =
 \lim_{t \to x_0} \frac{f(t)-f(x_0)}{g(t)-g(x_0)} = \cdots
$$
Do you see how to proceed? Make sure to justify why each step is valid.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I got it now!